# Can host ASP.NET Core site through console but not through IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

#### Solution and server configuration:

I have developed a fairly simple ASP.NET Core application. It consists of a core project file, created and built in Visual Studio 2017. The target framework is `.NETCoreApp 1.1` and Platform target is `x64`.

It also contains two class library projects with target frameworks `.NETStandard 1.4` and Platform target `x64`.

Due to a bug in VS2017's Web Deploy, I am publishing to file system, then copying the contents of `PublishOutput` to my IIS application's directory using FTP.

My server is Windows Server 2012 R2 with all relevant service packs and updates. DotNet Core runtimes have been installed.

#### The issue:

When I navigate to my site's URL in the browser, I encounter a bland HTML page which indicates the following:

```
HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Common causes of this issue: (lists things)
Troubleshooting steps: (lists things)
For more information visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=808681
```

#### Steps taken to resolve:

Needless to say, I've followed the instructions to resolve. [The link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=808681) given shows my error under the heading of **Platform conflicts with RID**.

The Event Viewer has an Error entry with the following:

```
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MY SITE' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\' failed to start process with commandline "dotnet" .\MySite.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80070002 : 0.
```

By opening an instance of `cmd.exe` at my site's folder, I can execute `dotnet mysite.dll` and it runs, hosting on `http://localhost:5000`. I can navigate to the site in a browser, as expected.

My `Program.cs` is as follows:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

host.Run();
```

My `Startup.cs` is mostly uninteresting. Excepting some service definitions, my pipeline is:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication();
app.UseRedditMiddleware(); // authentication middleware, custom
app.UseMvc();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either the system wide %PATH% to the dotnet folder is not set (IIS runs as a different user) or you did not restart your server after installing ASP.Net Core Server bundle. You can find more some troubleshooting steps in my post [about running ASP.NET Core applications with IIS](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/).

Comment: You're right. I indeed did not restart my server after installing since that after hosts other tenants and I didn't want downtime. After restarting, the site works.